# Getting input from a text box and updating a text area with what the input from the text box was

Tags: java, textbox

I'm trying to to pull the input from text box and add it to a text area. What my app does at the moment is it takes the text from the text box and writes it to a notepad file. When the app loads it loads that notepad file into the text area one line at a time. How would I go about updating the text area with the new input as well as writing it to the notepad file? I do not really have any code that would help with this since I already have working code that pulls from the text box and writes to the notepad file, I just want it to update the text area with the new input the moment the button is pressed to write to the notepad file.

Comment: Language, technology?  If it's a web app, in the browser, than you can do some javascript for this...if its a complied app it will require a different approach.  Please be more specific about your environment.

Comment: Oh wow, sorry, It is Java. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time understanding your requirements. You should reword your question.

If you want to write the data to the file, use `BufferedWriter`.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/path/to/file.extention");
BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(fw);  
buf.write(textArea.getText());
```

---

> How would I go about updating the text area with the new input

You just have to append the data that you read to the `JTextArea`.

```
String line = "";
while( (line = bufReader.readLine()) != null)){
   textArea.setText( textArea.getText() + line);
}
```

where `bufReader` is an instance of `BufferedReader`.

---

> the moment the button is pressed to write to the notepad file.

That requires knowing how to use an `ActionListener` with a `JButton`.

```
saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      // your logic to save the file goes here
   }
});
```